# Old Azure WebJob logs

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, azureportal

How to find old WebJob logs for Azure Web Service Application? I try to open `kudu` for selected Web application, and then go to  `data\jobs\triggered\WebJobVistracksSync`, but only current day logs there:

[image]

but I want to look at old log files, approx 1 month ago. Is it possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It only returns 50 results because that is all it saves by default. You could set the default value with `WEBJOBS_HISTORY_SIZE` in Application Settings.

From the WebJob [wiki](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/WebJobs#configuration-settings) , you could find it's about the Maximum number of runs kept in the history directory for a triggered job. And the default is 50.

If you still have other questions, please let me know.